# EmguCV & OpenCV: Whitelist RTP protocol

Tags: c#, emgucv, rtp, sdp

I am trying to receive some video from a Parrot Bebop 2 drone.
I am using this [Bebop.sdp](https://github.com/Parrot-Developers/application_notes/blob/master/BebopStreamVLC/bebop.sdp) file, which is supplied by Parrot.

I have previously tried in Python which worked by setting an environment variable `OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS` to `protocol_whitelist;file,rtp,udp`.
This worked in Python.
Since then we have ported that project mostly to C#. But when trying to connect to the stream, we get this error `Protocol 'rtp' not on whitelist 'file,crypto'!`.
I have seen other examples where this `-protocol_whitelist "file,rtp,udp"` is passed through ffmpeg arguments, but in this case it does not seem as a solution, since i cannot pass it on.

Firstly i started with a simple test:

```
VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture(0);
var frame = videoCapture.QueryFrame();

while (frame != null)
{
    using (frame)
    {
        CvInvoke.Imshow("frame", frame);
        CvInvoke.WaitKey(1);
    }

    frame = videoCapture.QueryFrame();
}
```

This code get's the stream from the webcam and works.

I get the error when i run it with the SDP file:

```
VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture(@"./bebop.sdp");

var frame = videoCapture.QueryFrame();

while (frame != null)
{
    using (frame)
    {
        CvInvoke.Imshow("frame", frame);
        CvInvoke.WaitKey(1);
    }

    frame = videoCapture.QueryFrame();
}
```

I have tried to add both:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS", "protocol_whitelist;file,rtp,udp");
```

And for a more aggressive approach:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS", "protocol_whitelist;file,rtp,udp", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

None of them seem to have an impact since i get same error.

I would expect when setting the environment variables that the OpenCV would whitelist the protocols needed so the stream would come trough, and be displayed in the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variable was working, however due to the need for Visual Studio to restart first, in order to update environment variables, this was not discovered before today.